# continuous integration with travis ci and openshift

Tags: git, continuous-integration, openshift, travis-ci

I try continuous integration with travis and openshift.

[**Travis log**](https://s3.amazonaws.com/archive.travis-ci.org/jobs/13603103/log.txt)

```
Total 387 (delta 202), reused 387 (delta 202)
error: Could not read f296a9effed3a7c3f86be451613e529c1818667b
fatal: revision walk setup failed
error: Could not read f296a9effed3a7c3f86be451613e529c1818667b
fatal: revision walk setup failed
remote: Stopping MongoDB cartridge[K
remote: Stopping Ruby cartridge[K
remote: [Wed Nov 06 16:24:47 2013] [warn] PassEnv variable SHELL was undefined[K
remote: [Wed Nov 06 16:24:47 2013] [warn] PassEnv variable USER was undefined[K
remote: [Wed Nov 06 16:24:47 2013] [warn] PassEnv variable LOGNAME was undefined[K
To ssh://527aafeb5973caf4e90007ca@audioblog-l33tname.rhcloud.com/~/git/audioblog.git/
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (missing necessary objects)
error: failed to push some refs to 'ssh://527aafeb5973caf4e90007ca@audioblog-l33tname.rhcloud.com/~/git/audioblog.git/'
```

**My question is:** What does this error mean or what I do wrong?

I have tried to recreate the openshift application. And check my passwort in my `.travis.yml` file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I push it initial from my local git repository `git push -f openshift master`

**.git/config**

```
[remote "openshift"]
    url = ssh://527aafeb5973caf4e90007ca@audioblog-l33tname.rhcloud.com/~/git/audioblog.git/
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/openshift/*
```

And now it deploy again, but I still interested in why this happened.

Comment: This does not answer your question. If this were still open, we may actually get a real answer

Comment: That is true but it solves the problem so it's probably for 90% of the people good enough (including me) and you can always provide a better answer if you find one